# C# membership multiple providers createuser error

Tags: c#, membership-provider

I declared 2 Membership Providers:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="ConnectionString1" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="2" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="30" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xzxzxz"/>
        <add connectionStringName="ConnectionString2" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="2" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="30" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProviderProduction" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

But when I am calling CreateUser using one of the providers:

```
var membershipProviderProduction = Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProviderProduction"];

MembershipUser newUser = membershipProviderProduction.CreateUser(username, password, email, question, answer, isAproved, out cs);
```

I get this error:

> Error 65  No overload for method 'CreateUser' takes 7 arguments

Comment: Like the first answer: The error is clear. You either have too little or to much arguments. What did googling tell you?... [msdn]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.createuser(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, As much as I know It has 8 parameters Check below

```
MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status);
```

You are missing 'providerUserKey' infact

Comment: well if I use Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, question, answer, isAproved, out cs); it works fine